# Losing connection with SQL Sever and Node on API request

Tags: node.js, sql-server, api, axios, es6-promise

I am trying to loop a query to get results of a given size and after I make the first query it gives me an error

I have tried to reopen the connection which it tells me it's already open and when I try to just use the first connection it says it is closed

```
axios.defaults.headers.common['X-API-KEY'] = apiKey;
axios.defaults.headers.common['Content-Type'] =  'application/json';
axios.defaults.baseURL = 'https://v2.namsor.com/NamSorAPIv2';

const selectStatment = "SELECT [CandidateId] AS id, ( CASE LEN(REPLACE([CandidateName],' ','')) WHEN LEN([CandidateName]) - 1 then PARSENAME(REPLACE([CandidateName],' ','.'), 2) ELSE PARSENAME(REPLACE([CandidateName],' ','.'), 3) END ) AS firstName, PARSENAME(REPLACE([CandidateName],' ','.'), 1) AS lastName ";
const cleanWherequery = 'WHERE NOT firstName IS NULL OR NOT firstName IS NULL ANd NOT lastName IS NULL';
const sqlTable = '##apiTable';
const tempQuery = `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ##apiTable, ##clean; ${selectStatment} INTO ##clean FROM [dbo].[DimCandidate]; SELECT * INTO ${sqlTable} FROM ##clean ${cleanWherequery}`;
const orderByFetch= `ORDER BY lastName DESC OFFSET ${i * 100} FETCH NEXT 100`
const countQuery = `SELECT COUNT(*) AS Count FROM ${sqlTable}`

const conn = new sql.ConnectionPool(dbConfig);

conn.connect()
.then(function(){
  const reqCount = new sql.Request(conn);

  reqCount.query(`${countQuery}`)
  .then(function(recordset){
    let opt = recordset.recordset[0]['Count'];
    let segCount = Math.ceil(opt/100);
    console.log(segCount);
    return segCount;
    sql.close()
  })
  .then(function(count){
    conn.connect()
    .then(function(){
      const req = new sql.Request(conn);
      for(let i = 0; i < count; i++){
        req.query(`SELECT TOP 201 id, firstName, lastName FROM ${sqlTable} ${orderByFetch}`)
        .then(function (recordset) {
          for(i = 0; i < count; i++){
            console.info(recordset.recordset);
            const jsonSet = {
              'personalNames': recordset.recordset
            }
            console.log(jsonSet);
            getRace(jsonSet);
            getGender(jsonSet)
          }
        }).catch(e =>{
          console.log(e);
        })
      }
  })
}).catch(function (err) {
    console.log(err);
    conn.close();
  })
})
.then(function(){
  conn.close();
})
.catch(err => {
  console.log(err);
  conn.close()
})
.catch(function(e){
  console.log(e);
})
```

The expected out come is to loop through the query and make a api request and the current problem is making the second query

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: connection is closed is the error i am receiving or when i try to create a new connection it says connection is already open. The current code gives ConnectionError: Connection not yet open. as the error

Comment: I'm not savvy with this code, but it looks like this might be causing your issue... `sql.close()` in the first function. Try changing that to `conn.close()` and see what happens.

Comment: I tried making the change i now receive  ConnectionError: Connection not yet open.

Comment: @WEI_DBA : But it looks to me like `sql.close()` is never reached because it is preceded by `return segCount;`

Comment: Which of the catch statements is catching the error?

Comment: I don't understand why there are two loops (nested) using the variable `count`. Don't you only need to use this on the outer loop where you are getting groups of 100 record?. It also looks like the `TOP 201` clause in the select in the main loop is redundant? IMHO the code could do with some cleaning up. Unless I completely misunderstand the logic.

Comment: @JohnRC I just have the TOP 201 because i don't want to run the whole query against the api before i have it working it won't be there once the code is running

Comment: Looking again I have a suspicion that your code which closes the connection, which you intend to run after all the db access has completed, may be running before you intend it to. I think the `.then( function(){ conn.close() } )` part of your chained functions is executed asynchronously from the execution of the SQL access code because the SQL access is part of a separate chain, which is nested at `conn.connect().then(...)`. The code within this inner `.then(..)` forms part of a separate async chain, which is run distinct from the outer chain. So the `conn.close()`  runs first.

Comment: You could check this by putting, say, `console.log("Closing connection");` before `conn.close();` and see if that is appears in your log before the error is caught.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have investigated further and have the answer to this problem - which is, as I suspected, due to nesting separate async sequences using promises.

The problem arises because the code creates two async paths, one within the other. You might be tempted to think that the outer async path waits for the inner to complete, but this is not the case - the inner path is initiated within the outer path but, once started, is executed separately, while the outer execution path continues asynchronously.

When using promises with `.then(...);` steps it is important to bear in mind that the function that handles the resolution of the promise is now on a separate execution path, and code that follows the `then(...);` clause is executed *before* the promise resolves.

To illustrate this I created a test function which clarifies the situation in the code from OP. The objective of the code is to carry out five steps:

1. Open a DB connection
2. Load data into a temp table
3. Read data from the temp table
4. Report the data
5. Close the DB Connection

The problem arises because, due to nesting of the `.then(..)` promises, step 5 is carried out before even step 2 is completed:

```
function TestLostConnection(){
    console.log( ">> START TestLostConnection")
    const loadTempTable = "IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##tempTable') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE ##tempTable; SELECT TOP(1) * INTO ##tempTable from Sys_TestData; ";
    const readTempTable = "SELECT * FROM ##tempTable;"

    // Get connection pool from DB API
    const conn = darwinDB.newConnectionPool();

    // Open the connnection, then access the database
    console.log( "  ### STEP 1: Initiating async database access" );
    conn.connect().then( 
        function(){ 
            console.log( ">> START ASYNC SEGMENT #1" );

            // Get a new request from the connection pool
            let req = new sql.Request(conn);

            // Use request to load the temp table
            console.log( "  ### STEP 2: Running query to load temp table" );
            req.query( loadTempTable ).then(
                function(){

                    console.log( ">> START ASYNC SEGMENT #2 - temp table has been loaded" );

                    // Get new reqeuest from connection pool
                    console.log( "Getting new Request from connection pool");
                    let reqCount = new sql.Request(conn);

                    console.log( "  ## STEP 3: running query to read data from ##tempTable");
                    reqCount.query(readTempTable).then(

                        function(recordset){
                            console.log( ">> START ASYNC SEGMENT #3 - Read from ##tempTable complete" );

                            // Report the data loaded from ##tempTable
                            console.log( "  ## STEP 4: Reporting data to the console")
                            console.dir( recordset );

                            console.log( "<< END ASYNC SEGMENT #3");
                        }
                    )
                    .catch(function (err) {

                        console.log("#### CATCH A")
                        console.log(err);
                        conn.close();
                    })

                    console.log( "<< END ASYNC SEGMENT #2 " )
                }
            ).catch(err => {
                    console.log("#### CATCH B")
                    console.log(err);
                    conn.close()
                }
            )

            console.log("<< END ASYNC SEGMENT #1")
        }
    ).then(function(){
            console.log( ">> START ASYNC SEGMENT #4")
            console.log( "  ## STEP 5: CLOSING CONNECTION" );
            conn.close();
            console.log( "<< END ASYNC SEGMENT #4")
        }
    ).catch(err => {
            console.log("#### CATCH C")
            console.log(err);
            conn.close()
        }
    )

    console.log( "<< END TestLostConnection")

}
```

This is the console output when the code is executed:

```
>> START TestLostConnection
   ### STEP 1: Initiating async database access
<< END TestLostConnection
>> START ASYNC SEGMENT #1
  ### STEP 2: Running query to load temp table
<< END ASYNC SEGMENT #1
>> START ASYNC SEGMENT #4
  ## STEP 5: CLOSING CONNECTION
<< END ASYNC SEGMENT #4
#### CATCH B
{ ConnectionError: Connection not yet open.
```